# Flutter equivalent of scrollIndicatorInsets to avoid safe area

Tags: flutter

Does Flutter have any way of reproducing iOS's UIScrollView's [scrollIndicatorInsets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naDeQ.gif) property to add padding to the top and bottom of [Scrollbar](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Scrollbar-class.html) scrolling indicators?

This allows scroll indicators to avoid safe areas, whilst content still renders in them, like this:

[image: Example GIF]

Most of the time UIKit manages this automatically.

Comment: Do you mean you only have issues with the `Scrollbar` (vertical line at the bottom right corner)? You want that to go down ?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad yes, it's the Scrollbar - I want to reproduce exactly what it's the GIF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doesn't seem to be any easy way to do this.

There's an open issue about this on the Flutter repo: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25802

Comment: A fix for this has just landed in Flutter's master channel; should be coming to the next Flutter stable release.